# How to send a value through the btn for the route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

Hi I'm beginner and i would like to know how can I send the Id of the event to the "/checkin" route when the btn is clicked.

here is the code:

```
        {{#each events}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{this.subject}}<br><a href="/checkin" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Click here to checkin</a>
    </td>
          <td>{{this.location.displayName}}</td>
          <td>{{eventDateTime this.start.dateTime}}</td>
          <td>{{eventDateTime this.end.dateTime}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it trough the route! with something like this:

```
href={"/checkin?EventId=" + event.id }
```

or

```
href={`/checkin?EventId=${event.id}`}
```

And when /checkin load just use this line of code to get the value:

```
new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('EventId')
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: It returns this error "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the event ID as a query param, you could just concat it to the route like this:

```
      {{#each events}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{this.subject}}<br><a href={`/checkin?id=${this.id}`} class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Click here to checkin</a>
    </td>
          <td>{{this.location.displayName}}</td>
          <td>{{eventDateTime this.start.dateTime}}</td>
          <td>{{eventDateTime this.end.dateTime}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
```